# How to update dotnetnuke userprofile image in codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am building my own `"user profile"` module where one of the options, the user can change his default `dnn` profile image. I am having problems doing this "in the code behind". I am using `c#`.

This is what I have so far:

```
UserInfo myDnnUser = this.UserInfo;
myDnnUser.Profile.InitialiseProfile(PortalId);

myDnnUser.Profile.SetProfileProperty("Photo", "new filename");
myDnnUser.Profile.SetProfileProperty("PhotoURL", "new url");

ProfileController.UpdateUserProfile(myDnnUser);
```

But its not working, and when I view the "File" table that dnn uses, its still the same (old) filename.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three tables involved: `UserProfile`, `ProfilePropertyDefinition` and `Files`.

UserProfile stores PropertyValues for ProfilePropertyDefinitions.

Expected PropertyValue for a "Photo" PropertyName is a FileID reference to the Files table, not a file name. Before setting the Photo, you need to get the FileID:

```
    var objFiles = new FileController();
    FileInfo objFile = objFiles.GetFile("filepath", PortalID);
    myDnnUser.Profile.Photo = objFile.FileId;
    ProfileController.UpdateUserProfile(myDnnUser);
```

PhotoURL is a read-only property that retrieves the url for the UserProfile's Photo property.